# How to pass javascript variables through a form?

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing, forms, http-post

How can I pass these two variables `val_1` & `val_2` through a form submission to the function `initComparison()`?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="">    
 <select name="val_1">
   <option value="x">X</option>
   <option value="y">Y</option>

 <input type="text" value="Enter the product id" name="val_2">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
    initComparison('val_1','val_2','abc','def');
 });</script>
```

Comment: By listening to the `submit` event.

Comment: I don't know how to work with it. Can you please help me with a piece of code?

Comment: it is fairly simple to research how to get values of form elements. It really doesn't appear like you tried searching for solutions or methods. Asking questions here shouldn't be your first point of research

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
      <form action="" onsubmit="">    
        <select name="val_1" id="val_1">
            <option value="x">X</option>
            <option value="y">Y</option>
         </select>
          <input type="text" value="Enter the product id" name="val_2" id="val_2">
          <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="send">
      </form>

         <script type="text/javascript"> 
             $("#send").click(function(){
                 var var1=$("#val_1").val();
                 var var2=$("#val_2").val();

             initComparison(val_1,val_2,'abc','def');
          });
         </script>
```